# OpenGL C++ Scene Navigation with mouse

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math

My goal is to navigate in the view port using the mouse.

Every frame that the mouse move, I recalculate the cameraFront and cameraUp vectors and finally the view matrix. The problem is that the view matrix sometimes create rotation in the z axis, witch I don't expected to be.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
glm::vec3 cameraPos = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);
glm::vec3 cameraFront = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
glm::vec3 cameraUp = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
   if (firstMouse)
   {
       lastX = xpos;
       lastY = ypos;
       firstMouse = false;
   }

   float xoffset = xpos - lastX;
   float yoffset = ypos - lastY;

   lastX = xpos;
   lastY = ypos;

   float sensitivity = 0.05;
   xoffset *= sensitivity;
   yoffset *= sensitivity;

   glm::quat rotY = glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(xoffset), cameraUp);
   cameraFront = glm::normalize(rotY * cameraFront);

   glm::vec3 rightAxis = glm::cross(cameraUp, cameraFront);

   glm::quat rotX = glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(yoffset), rightAxis);
   cameraFront = glm::normalize(rotX * cameraFront);

   cameraUp = glm::normalize(glm::cross(cameraFront, rightAxis));
}
```

in the while loop am recalculate the view matrix:

```
view = glm::lookAt(cameraPos, cameraPos + cameraFront, cameraUp);
```

I am learning OpenGl from the [Tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera) which show example how to navigate in the scene, but I am trying to it differently.
can anyone see my mistake?